# Timeline based animations on the iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, flash, ipad, timeline, animation

How would you go about creating a timeline animation for an iPhone or iPad application? I'm looking for something like a timeline animation in Flash. I don't need a technical explanation on how to program it, though.

So here are some general questions:
- I read something about UIView for PNG sequences, but aren't these kind of animations resource intensive? And what about filesize? PNG can't be compressed like jpeg.
- What about vector-like animations? These would save a lot of kb's.
- Are there animation frameworks like TweenLite/TweenMax/Tweener/... (some well known frameworks for animations in ActionScript) ?
- Any good references on how to make animations (like Text animations, ...)

Thanks in advance.

Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple pretty much spells it out in [Getting Started with Graphics and animation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Graphics_iPhone/).

In general just stick with the highest possible API, and test to see if it's going to meet your needs or not. Moving around a UIView or UILabel (text) as in a Timeline Animation not only takes just a couple of lines of code but it will probably perform just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This only just came out, but have you heard of Hirameki?

It's a flash animation parser that lets you drop SWF animations directly into Xcode projects for iPhone. A demonstration and beta sign up is here http://www.flash-on-iphone.com

Comment: Looks like it hasn't even come out yet (as of nearly 2 months after this post, all that exists are some demos -- on video, no less -- and a beta signup form).